# Why is not possible passing event name as argument to a composite component in JSF 2?

Tags: jsf-2, composite-component

Why can't I pass event name as argument to a composite component bean in JSF 2.

This works:

```html
<f:ajax event="click"
        render="#{cc.attrs.ajaxRender}"
        execute="#{cc.attrs.ajaxExecute}"
        immediate="#{cc.attrs.immediate}"/>
```

This doesn't:

```html
<f:ajax event="#{cc.attrs.itemEvent}"
        render="#{cc.attrs.ajaxRender}"
        execute="#{cc.attrs.ajaxExecute}"
        immediate="#{cc.attrs.immediate}"/>
```

Question is: why?
NOTE: eventName is actually defined in cc:interface as the following:

```html
<composite:attribute name="itemEvent" default="click"/>
```

Comment: This seems to be [a bug](https://java.net/jira/browse/JAVASERVERFACES_SPEC_PUBLIC-622) in the Mojarra 2.1.x versions. Are you using any of them? Should be solved for 2.2.x.

Comment: @XtremeBiker it sure is. Thank you.